# Image doesn't show when I send an email / swiftmailer

Tags: php, swift, image, email, swiftmailer

I am currently using Swiftmailer to send my emails. Everything works fine it is sending the emails however the emails are not showing the Logo I have put in. Here is the code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'config/constants.php';

// Create the Transport
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl'))
        ->setUsername(EMAIL)
        ->setPassword(PASSWORD);

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);


function sendVerificationEmail($userEmail, $token){
    global $mailer;
    $body = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Verify Email</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="not-verified-container">
    <img src="logo.svg" class="mazaw-logo-not-verified">
    <div class="container-without-logo">
        <div class="not-verified-texts">
            <h2>Account Verification</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>';
    // Create a message
    $message = (new Swift_Message('Account Verification'))
        ->setFrom(EMAIL)
        ->setTo($userEmail)
        ->setBody($body, 'text/html');
// Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
}
```

I would be very very thankful if someone could take a look and see what I have done wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: That is because that image is local to you.

Comment: This question IMHO is a typographical error.

Comment: following suggestions above:
`<img src="http://www.website.com/path/logo.svg" class="mazaw-logo-not-verified">`

Comment: Please don't deface the question. If you want to delete it instead, do. Just don't edit it with a bunch of nonsense. I rolled it back to a previous revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding should work fine

```
<?php    
$message = new Swift_Message('Your subject');
$message->setBody(
'<html>' .
' <body>' .
'  <img src="' . $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('image.png')) . '" />' .
' </body>' .
'</html>',
'text/html'
);    
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the logo image in the email as an attachment. Not sure how thats done in Swiftmailer but when I googled it there are numerous examples including this one from here in StackOverflow.

[Swiftmailer Attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416583/swift-mailer-attachment)

```
$uploadedFileName = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'career_resume'); 
$uploadedFileName = $uploadedFile->tempName; // will be something like 'myfile.jpg'
$swiftAttachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($uploadedFileName);
$message->attach($swiftAttachment);
```

Also Google how to embed an image in Swiftmailer.